# How do I get a Haxe OpenFL project to use an external swf library?

Tags: actionscript, haxe, openfl

I've read documentation and tried to get my OpenFL project to use an external swf library and I keep getting an error that it can't find the classes when I run the project.

As a test I added a swf that has an actionscript lib for using Twitter. I created a github project here https://github.com/matthewswallace/TestOpenFL

The error I get when running the project is the following.

```
src/Main.hx:7: characters 7-34 : Class not found : com.swfjunkie.tweetr.Tweetr
Error: Command failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Swf library deals with graphics only, Any actionscript will be dropped, you need to port your actionscript classes to haxe and use them in your project directly ..

Comment: I thought there was a way to create Externs for AS3 libraries and then at compile it would play nice and use external AS3 code.

Comment: If so, then flash player will be a dependency for your project to work correctly regardless of your platform target .. I don't think so..